# Implementation of Dijkstra's algorithm [I'm confused by a questions formatting]

Tags: algorithm, graph, dijkstra, binary-heap

I am currently working on a homework assignment that requires me to:

> Implement DIJKSTRA's algorithm for Single Source Shortest Path Problem
>   with BINARY Heaps. The running time should be O(ElogV).

Simple enough! However, the problem must be solved via code. Still not all that difficult a concept until this:

> Your program should read data from file (see samples below) and output
>   a single number = sum of lengths of the shortest paths from node 0 to
>   each node.  INPUT FORMAT: The first line of each file below contains
>   the number of vertices and the number of edges in the graph (in the
>   format "n=XXXX m=XXXXX"). The rest of the file is organized as
>   follows:  each vertex i appears on a line by itself, followed by a
>   line for each neighbor j>i of i (containing j and the length of edge
>   (i,j)). Each list of neighbors is ended by an empty line. Vertices i
>   which do not have neighbors with an index greater than i are not
>   represented.  NOTE: Vertices are indexed from 0 to n-1.  NOTE: each
>   edge is mentioned only once with its smaller number endpoint  SAMPLE
>   INPUT: 
>   1. [first input](http://www.cs.gsu.edu/~cscazz/CS4520/25000.txt) 
>   2. [second input](http://www.cs.gsu.edu/~cscazz/CS4520/1000.txt)  the length of the shortest path tree should be 10721073 and 625349 respectively.  Program should give output in 3-10
>   seconds for the first input and less than 1 second for the second.

**My question(s):** I don't quite understand my professor's explanation for the file's formats and how they should translate in code. Neither do I understand what kind of graph I am supposed to visualize, am I finding the shortest path on a binary tree or am I finding the shortest path on a graph (not a binary tree) with many vertices and edges? (I get confused cause he mentions Binary Heaps so I am not sure what to visualize here)

**What about the files I don't understand:** Looking at the graph we have something like this:

```
n=25000 m=576014
0
   176     67
   665    185
  1129     26
  1414    114
  1748    205
  2027    264
  2714    212
  2743    132 ...
```

From his explanation I understand that `n = number of vertices` and `m = number of edges`. What I don't understand is what the pairs of numbers after the vertex `0` represent in terms of the graph I'm supposed to use Dijkstra's on. Also if you look at the end of either of the files you'll notice that the numbers of vertices listed in this format is not the name number that `n ='s`. Why is this?

Comment: From a quick reading, it seems that vertex `0` is connected to vertex `176` with cost `67`, to vertex `665` with cost `185`, and so on.

Comment: And based on that reading it's definitely a graph.

Comment: This answers one question but begs many more. Thanks for the responses guys.